# Javascript Date Object from string in form 'HH-MM'

Tags: javascript, date, time

Hey, just wondering how to convert an `HH:MM` string into a javascript `Date` object. I have tried `new Date(string);` and `myDate.setTime()` but to no avail.

A side question could be: How to convert a string in `HH:MM` into milliseconds from Jan 1, 1970.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in JavaScript, I'm using the datejs library. http://www.datejs.com/
If you include this library, you have a function called "parseExact" and you could use it like this:

```
var dateString = "10-12";
var date = new Date.parseExact(dateString, "hh-mm");
```

To get the miliseconds, you can download the file time.js from http://code.google.com/p/datejs/source/browse/trunk/#trunk/src. Then you have a function getTotalMilliseconds() you can use:

```
var mSeconds = date.getTotalMilliseconds();
```

I hope this will help a little bit.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. Sorry I can't vote you up yet (limit reached) but I now realise that my question was wrong, I meant `HH:MM`. If your answer still works for it, well then I'm happy.

Comment: This function parses any datetime-string. View some examples here: http://www.datejs.com/test/parseExact/index.html. And this functions also parses Date.parseExact(dateString, "HH-MM"). In my option it is more safety and elegant to use a parser-method instead of doing it manual.

Comment: P.S. This helps _a lot._ And thanks for the very comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 9):

How about something like:

```
//using timestr '10:33:21', could also be '10-33-21'
var dat = new Date, time = timestr.split(/\:|\-/g);
dat.setHours(time[0]);
dat.setMinutes(time[1]);
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is too "manual". There are parsing methods that can do the work.

Comment: As always [in javascript], there are many roads leading to Rome. This is one of them. I think it's usefull to know what one is doing before switching to more abstracted frameworks or libraries. It's a matter of taste I suppose.

Comment: what about AM/PM?